# Hello i would like to know why in certain width screen the overflow is hidden?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hello I would like to know why in certain width screen the overflow is hidden ? Are there any solutions ?
Thank you

http://4s.bnd-dev.fr/

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GbzP.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF3wH.jpg)

Comment: because on the left is a sidebar with vertical text.

Comment: i tried to put a z-index 0 for the sidebar but its still not working. 
I don't think the problem is the sidebar because the text is overflowing in >1367px though

Comment: Do you want the animation text to be on top of the sidebar?

Comment: yes i do, i want it to overflow

Comment: I found the problem. I will give the answer now

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: did you manage to fix the problem?

Comment: thank you for the answer i will try it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to overlap the left side block with the text marquee, you need to set a rule with margin. You have this rule in the selector - `.elementor-62 .elementor-element.elementor-element-25c4ac8>.elementor-widget-container`, and you can see it if you click on `<div class = "elementor-widget-container">`.

And this is the very rule that needs to be changed - `margin: -55px -7px -40px -103px;`.

In order to move your marquee, you need to change the 4th parameter of this rule, i.e. `-103px`.

If you have any questions, please contact.

Comment: i tried to change the 4th parameter and it still the same, no result. The marquee is still cut for screens that are <1367px

Comment: I made a gif for you. Look here - https://ibb.co/Qf0yYnv.

Comment: And made the second hypha. Customization through the browser object inspector - https://ibb.co/q7MLg3h.

Comment: it's working, thank you very much ! thank you for your time ! I appreciate a lot

Comment: Always glad to help )